# How to store the details of a Amazon EC2 instance in varibles and then use the variables to launch more

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, boto3

```
 import boto.ec2
 import time
 import sys
 conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("ap-southeast-1")

 reservations=conn.get_all_instances(sys.argv[1])
 instances = [i for r in reservations for i in r.instances]
 for i in instances:
     print(i.__dict__)
```

The above code is able to fetch details of the instance i provide as argument, i need to launch a new instance from the ami of this instance, how do i store the details in a variable and then use it to launch a new instance in same VPC??

Comment: simple store it in a JSON object and re-use it at will.

Comment: could you help with the actual code to store it in json.. that will be really helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

So you need go through the attributes of `instance` , (replace `i` with `instance` to make sense)

```
>>> instance.image_id
u'ami-XXXXXXX'

>>> instance.vpc_id
u'vpc-XXXXXXXX'

>>> dir(instance)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_in_monitoring_element', '_placement', '_previous_state', '_state', '_update', 'add_tag', 'add_tags', 'ami_launch_index', 'architecture', 'block_device_mapping', 'client_token', 'confirm_product', 'connection', 'create_image', 'dns_name', 'ebs_optimized', 'endElement', 'eventsSet', 'get_attribute', 'get_console_output', 'group_name', 'groups', 'hypervisor', 'id', 'image_id', 'instance_profile', 'instance_type', 'interfaces', 'ip_address', 'item', 'kernel', 'key_name', 'launch_time', 'modify_attribute', 'monitor', 'monitored', 'monitoring', 'monitoring_state', 'persistent', 'placement', 'placement_group', 'placement_tenancy', 'platform', 'previous_state', 'previous_state_code', 'private_dns_name', 'private_ip_address', 'product_codes', 'public_dns_name', 'ramdisk', 'reason', 'reboot', 'region', 'remove_tag', 'remove_tags', 'requester_id', 'reset_attribute', 'root_device_name', 'root_device_type', 'sourceDestCheck', 'spot_instance_request_id', 'start', 'startElement', 'state', 'state_code', 'state_reason', 'stop', 'subnet_id', 'tags', 'terminate', 'unmonitor', 'update', 'use_ip', 'virtualization_type', 'vpc_id']
```

If you need run a new instance, please go through

[lounching-instances](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ec2_tut.html#launching-instances)

[part of run_instances](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#module-boto.ec2)

Answer (score 0):

Take the code below as reference, use instance.image_id to fetch the image id , and then launch new instances using run_instances method.

```
from boto.regioninfo import *
from boto.ec2.connection import EC2Connection

instances = ['enter instance id here']
key_name = "keyname"
security_group = ['security group ids in array']
instance_type = "c3.xlarge"
subnet_name = "subnet-id"

# AWS connect info
aws_access_key_id='########## AWS Access Key ############'
aws_secret_access_key='########### AWS Secret Key ############'
region_name='ap-southeast-1'
region_ec2_endpoint='ec2.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com'
# Connect EC2
aws_region = RegionInfo(name=region_name, endpoint=region_endpoint)
conn = EC2Connection(aws_access_key_id,aws_secret_access_key,region=aws_region)

reservations = conn.get_all_instances(instance_ids=instances)
instances = [i for r in reservations for i in r.instances]
for i in instances:
    image_id = i.image_id
    reserve = conn.run_instances(image_id=image_id,key_name=key_name,subnet_id=subnet_name ,instance_type=instance_type,security_group_ids =security_group)
    print "new system id is " + reserve.instances[0].id
```